# CoffeeScript -> Javascript -> Browserify -> Minify source map

Tags: coffeescript, browserify, source-maps

I have the above workflow for my project. I would like to use multi-level source maps to be able to debug my CoffeeScript files.

I found a tutorial, that explained source maps for the CoffeeScript -> Javascript -> Minify process:

http://www.thecssninja.com/javascript/multi-level-sourcemaps

but how could I add to it the Browserify step?

Comment: I highly recommend trying webpack. It replaces whole pipeline you described and elegantly recompiles everything as soon as your source files change.

Comment: I also recommend webpack over browserify. You should check out their [docs regarding devtool](http://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#devtool) and the [coffee loader](https://github.com/webpack/coffee-loader).